# Is there a profile revision history?

Tags: support, profile-page

I had some personal info shown on my profile, and I removed it.

I'm just curious: **Does a record of profile revisions, much like post revision history, exist?**

If so, who can access it? Mods? Devs? Anonymous users :p?

Comment: I'm sure the NSA has a copy...

Comment: I'm digging through your Programmers profile to see if there's any other information I've missed. If you find yourself suspended, I either found something nasty or I clicked the wrong button... And if there's a knock on the door, jumping out the window might be a good idea...

Comment: @Yannis Is the '*send waffles and unicorns*' button right by the '*suspend and make monitor emit gamma rays*' button?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are talking about your profile's about box, there's no revision history, at least not one that's accessible to moderators. There is a log entry that tells us you've updated your profile, but it doesn't tell us what the previous version was.

As for the rest of the information in your profile, we have access to a list of your past e-mails,  usernames and avatars.

Comment: I guess only email hash is available by [data.SE]

Comment: I posted a link on my profile once, but the link is gone from my profile now. I hope I'll still be able to access my profile's revision history somehow, so that I can recover the link that I had.

Comment: @AndersonGreen Hm, what? Read my answer again, there's no revision history.

Comment: @Yannis You said "at least not one that's accessible to moderators", so I had thought there might be some other way to access the revision history. I hope it isn't completely impossible to access previous versions of a profile description - if that's the case, then I'm completely out of luck.

Comment: Note: This answer is true only when a user edits their own "About me" section. When a mod edits a user's "About me" section, a revision history entry is stored for that change. This diff is linked from the user history page that mods can access.