# Add "About me" revisions

Tags: feature-request, profile-page, revisions-list

I would like to have a history of the "About me" box in my profile.

I edited my details on my profile page and it replaced all profiles with the same content, so I'd like to be able to go back to the old information.

Having a complete history of all information would be of use to moderators.

Comment: (This history would also be useful when moderators have to change something. Records are good.)

Comment: @minitech You can use Google cache to retrieve (as I am doing now) recent changes, but it becomes quit tricky when you your name changes because the URL changes `http://unix.stackexchange.com/users/0000/oldname` to `http://unix.stackexchange.com/users/0000/newname` therefore a search for `cache:http://unix.stackexchange.com/users/0000/newname` does't work.

Comment: I left an important link on my profile description, and then I accidentally removed it. I hope I will be able to recover the link from the profile's revision history.

Comment: Such thing currently doesn't exist, so it's a feature request. @AndersonGreen I doubt there's any revision history in the database, your data is most likely lost.

Comment: @AndersonGreen try the Internet Archive Wayback Machine: http://web.archive.org/web/20121227062930/http://stackoverflow.com/users/975097/anderson-green, it captured your SO profile a few times every month since Mai 12, chances are good you can recover it from there if the link has been in your profile for a while.

Comment: I also found a duplicate of this question: [Is there a profile revision history?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/187754/is-there-a-profile-revision-history)

Comment: @kapep There is still a bounty on this question, so you should post your comment as an answer.

Comment: @AndersonGreen thanks for reminding me! I made the answer a bit more general for future visitors.

Comment: @kapep nice, those are pretty easy 300 or 150 points! ;)

Comment: +1. I had site specific About Me's on two sites (travel and amateur radio), and one techie profile from StackOverflow which I'm happy to propagate to the numerous other Stack sites I have accounts at. Unfortunately, updating the About Me for all sites overwrote at the 2 sites which have a different About Me. (Entirely logical of course). In future I will have to remember to save any "custom" About Mes before updating my network profile, but it would have been really handy here to have a revision history.

Comment: [meta-tag:status-declined]

Comment: @iDebug Are you asking me to add that tag?

Comment: @William You surely can't. It's a moderator tag that can only be added/removed by a ♦. By that I mean this will likely be declined.

Comment: @Ry-: When a mod edits a user's "About me" section, a revision history entry is stored for that change. This diff is linked from the user history page that mods can access. (I'm guessing that wasn't always the case.)

Answer (score 7):

The [Internet Archive’s Wayback Machine](https://archive.org/web/web.php) captures profiles every now and then.

Use a profile's url and choose any date to show the content of the profile from that time. It's not a complete revision history though and you will still need some luck finding a particular revision, especially if that revision has been online only for a short time.

It's not really clear when the profile page will be crawled. Some captures are only days apart while sometimes there are no captures for weeks or months. The FAQ says it can take some month until a site's captured version will appear.

Comment: Hmm, could work, maybe, but I keep getting, 

"Hrm.

Wayback Machine doesn't have that page archived."