# Add "About Me" Confirmation to "Save and copy changes to all Stack Exchange Communities"

Tags: feature-request, profile-page

This somewhat solves my issues with  [these](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/197083/add-about-me-revisions) two [questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/137933/allow-save-and-copy-profile-to-all-stack-exchange-accounts-to-exclude-selected).

I would like to add a Add Confirmation Box to "Save and copy changes to all Stack Exchange Communities" to insure I don't keep accidentally hitting the button.